# Initialize item data on drop item in Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

here I create [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-colntrols-ffbkb3?file=app/reusable-form-component/reusable-form-component.component.html) of what I need. Open a console to see `console.log()`.

Problem is when I `DROP` item to `drop zone` array is empty (see console), but when u type something or select something, on `valueChange` I get data (also, check in console).

I need it on load before I select something or type something...  I want to get data when I `drop` item.

I use `emit()` to get data between component with template `reusable-form-component.component` and with main component `cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example`

I try with `[attr.init]` but i get `undefined`

Comment: Hi Alter hope you remember me :-). and i think you still stuck in that... let me finish it and i will be back

Comment: yes man, I remember you... i rly stuck with this... with this in my question and with deleted item inside `FORM` div... if I have different item it's ok, i delete it with `arr.slice(index, 1)` but if I have multiple same form like multiple select box, or input field, they always delete wrong item (one of them but with wrong index)....

Comment: do you also want a delete button for control ?

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil did you find something for delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `AfterViewInit` I have modified the code for you and added this
[click here for demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-colntrols)

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    debugger
    if (this.getFormControl == "INPUT")
      this.valueChange.emit({
        index: this.index,
        type: "INPUT",
        value: this.val
      });
    else if (this.getFormControl == "SELECT_BOX") {
      this.valueChange.emit({
        index: this.index,
        type: "SELECT_BOX",
        selectedValue: this.val,
        avaliableOptions: [
          "select option 1",
          "select option 2",
          "select option 3"
        ]
      });
    }
  }
```

You can [Click here](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) to see more details for **AfterViewInit** interface

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to add an element to container.data, not use transferArray, your drop function must be like

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      this.index= this.index+1;
      event.container.data.splice(event.currentIndex,
                       0,event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex])
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770939/cdk-drop-list-always-sets-the-list-items-from-initial-index-in-angular