# CDK drop List always sets the list items from initial index in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I have this cdk Drag drop

```
<div class="example-container" cdkDropListGroup>
Thus to describe data, one needs to know the extent of variability. This is given by the measures of dispersion.
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="done" class="example-list" cdkDropListSortingDisabled (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
<div class="example-box drobtnstyle" cdkDrag>{{ done[0] }}</div>
</div>
,
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="done" class="example-list" cdkDropListSortingDisabled (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
<div class="example-box drobtnstyle" cdkDrag>{{ done[1] }}</div>
</div>
    
, and
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="done" class="example-list" cdkDropListSortingDisabled (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
 <div class="example-box drobtnstyle" cdkDrag>{{ done[2] }}</div>
 </div>
 are the three commonly used measures of dispersion.
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="todo" class="example-list" cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"   (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
<button class="example-box btn drobtn2 " *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{ item }}</button>
</div>
</div>
```

> Link :
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnirx8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

There are three blanks items where user can place any of the todo items in `done[0]`,`done[1]` and  `done[2]`. But issue is if i place any item at done[2] position it automatically starts with `done[0]` position.

Any solution is highly appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using 3 different arrays for the 3 different done lists

```js
done1 = [];
done2 = [];
done3 = [];
```

```html
<div
    cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="done1"
    class="example-list"
    cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
>
    <div class="example-box" cdkDrag *ngFor="let i of done1">{{ i }}</div>
</div>
<span> ,are the three commonly used measures of dispersion.</span>
<div
    cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="done2"
    class="example-list"
    cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
>
    <div class="example-box" cdkDrag *ngFor="let i of done2">{{ i }}</div>
</div>

<span>, and are the three commonly used measures of dispersion.</span>
<div
    cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="done3"
    class="example-list"
    cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
>
    <div class="example-box" cdkDrag *ngFor="let i of done3">{{ i }}</div>
</div>
```